# Java - Playing a Sound file from the Internet

Tags: java, audio, javasound

For my assignment I have to playing a honking sound when a button is pressed. My professor doesn't want us to play the sound off of a local drive but from some website ex. "http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1696&type=wav" He supplied us with some code but I can't seem to get it to work. First is the method that is invoked when the button is pressed and the second is the class that is supposed to play the sound.

```
public void Honk(){
JavaSound player = new JavaSound();
player.playFile("http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1696&type=wav");   
}

class JavaSound {
public void playFile(String file) {
try {
URL soundToPlay = getClass().getResource(file);
AudioClip player = Applet.newAudioClip(soundToPlay);
player.play();
} catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: We help people find _solutions_ not problems to their code. So, you need to tell _us_ what is going wrong and then we can help you fix it. Are you getting any errors? What happens when you run it? In your catch block you should print out the stack trace of the exception so you can see what happened.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors and when I run it and when I click on the button nothing happens. How would I go about printing a stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Put `e.printStackTrace();` in the empty block in your `catch` - **never** ignore exceptions like that.

Comment: saying `catch (Exception e) {}` is the same as saying "I don't care if anything goes wrong" :) . Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?