# How to put sounds from the internet on html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put sounds and music on my program, this code works just fine when I call it as long as I have the archive downloaded on my pc, I want to know if there is a way to play it by a direct link from the Internet or something else so i don't need its archive downloaded.

```js
function music() {
    var musics = ["archive.mp3"]
    for(var i = 0;i<musics.length;i++){
        var music =new Audio(musics[z])
        music.play()
    }
}
```

I tried putting URLs on the place of the archive and even other formats but I can't get it to work, when I try to put an URL from YouTube/SoundCloud/some open sound libraries for example and it says no supported source is found.

It seems like the same problem as this guy who didn't get any response:[Java - Playing a Sound file from the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390319/java-playing-a-sound-file-from-the-internet)

Comment: _"I tried puting urls on the place of the archive and even other formats"_ Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72410534/edit) to show examples of the other URLs that did not work. Note that YouTube URLs will never work, since they are not audio files.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to post your code as a [mcve] before posting a question. In order to post a [mcve] ⏩ [look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg) ⏪

Comment: "*seems like the same problem as this guy who didnt get any response*" Please make sure you fully understand that the [tag:java] language is absolutely NOT the same as the [tag:javascript] language when searching for potential solutions in the future.

Comment: @zer00ne sorry mate i thought this {} was where i should put the code

Comment: @esqew yeah my bad didnt saw if it was the same language just the same problem

Comment: @Gringot You edited your question, but you did not include any other URLs that you tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the HTML `<audio></audio>` tag and add the source of your audio clip, as seen in the example below.

If you want more examples, check out this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

I hope this helps you.

```html
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://assets.mixkit.co/sfx/preview/mixkit-arcade-retro-game-over-213.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: yeah thats it thank you so much all i need now is to find out how you got that direct link and sorry for all those saying im not being clear enough and dont know how to use this

Comment: Hey @Gringot. All you have to do, is upload your audio file to a web server and get the link to your file. One option could be to use your Google drive and get the link to the file and use it. Make sure the file is publicly available before you use it inside your html.

Comment: thanks so much man going to try it already upvoted but as i said im new here so i dont have the 15 reputation nedded to my upvote to really count lol